# Store json object in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Quick question, I have a JSON data object for example `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }` , is it possible to store this just as it is in a mysql field?, and in turn read it?

Comment: The quick answer is of course YES

Comment: Google is your friend: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Answer (score 3):

You can store basically whatever you want in a MySQL field, the only constraints are the datatype and maximum size of the field. Whether that makes sense is another matter, and depends on the your use case. Two cases that make sense are as follows:

If you simply need a place to store a serialized array/object somewhere, and you don't need to query the fields in the serialized data, you can store it into e.g. a `varchar` or a `text` field like any other string, and simply `json_encode` on the way in and `json_decode` when reading it.

On the other hand, e.g. for a use case where you have variable data structures associated with your main table entries, which you need to query, you can use the [JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) (available since MySQL 5.7.8). The JSON datatype only accepts valid JSON strings for input, and there are [several useful functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) for querying the contents.

Whatever you do, don't store JSON (or other serialized data) into a regular text field, and then try to query it with `LIKE '%"field":"value"%'` style hacks. They yield misery and eventually fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should define the column properly (I usually define them as text). After that you can use json_decode() and that's it

Comment: Then you are storing text, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

MySQL does support JSON objects, so something a little like this:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT jdoc FROM t1;
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| jdoc                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

There is also a lot more functionality using JSON, so take a look at the documentation.